# How to megre two sorted lists in one sorted list

Tags: python, merge

I need to make a python task which combine two sorted list in one sorted list. I've try to use below code, but I receive: **sytax error**. Can someone can explain where is an error?

```
l1 = [1, 3, 4, 7]
l2 = [0, 2, 5, 6, 8, 9]

def merge_sorted_lists(l1, l2):
    """Merge sort two sorted lists

    Arguments:
    - `l1`: First sorted list
    - `l2`: Second sorted list
    """
    sorted_list = []

    # Copy both the args to make sure the original lists are not
    # modified
    l1 = l1[:]
    l2 = l2[:]

    while (l1 and l2):
        if (l1[0] <= l2[0]): # Compare both heads
            item = l1.pop(0) # Pop from the head
            sorted_list.append(item)
        else:
            item = l2.pop(0)
            sorted_list.append(item)

    # Add the remaining of the lists
    sorted_list.extend(l1 if l1 else l2)

    return sorted_list

if __== '__main__':
  print merge_sorted_lists(l1, l2)
```

help

Comment: Can you provide the error message? That makes it easier to identify the location of your error.

Comment: Just to note... while I'm guessing this is an exercise of some sort, generally you wouldn't need to write your own method for this, Python already comes with a library function that can do this: `list(heapq.merge(l1, l2))`.

Comment: (that or you could also do: `return sorted(l1 + l2)`... which might not be too bad performance wise as the sort algorithm CPython uses can take advantage of already sorted sequences...)

Comment: in you main. Is "if _ _name_ _ == '_ _main_ _': ". You have to verify if the __name__ variable is the main, is a way to python to know which file you are working. Besides that if you are using python3+ the print function have ( )

Comment: If don't be clear yet I can answer with the code example.

Comment: error message is: syntax error for  print merge_sorted_lists(l1, l2)

Comment: python3 changed the syntax of the print statement. Use `print(merge_sorted_lists(l1, l2))`

Answer (score -1):

**Use this Code for sorted list**

```
l1 = [1, 3, 4, 7]
l2 = [0, 2, 5, 6, 8, 9]


def combine(l1, l2):
    new_list = []
    for i in l1:
        new_list.append(i)
    for j in l2:
        new_list.append(j)
    return sorted(new_list)

print(combine(l1,l2))
```

Comment: Thank you. However, I need to use "merge".